# iOS 8 UIActivityViewController and/or UIPopoverController are not dissmissed when clicked outside of them

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have read the [UIPopoverController docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html) and more then 10 stackoverflow solutions which none work in iOS 8.0.2 ipad device.

THE GOAL:

I want to present a sharing view which when clicked outside dissmisses.

THE PROBLEM:

The code works fine below iOS 8.0.

THE CODE (tried many versions...):

```
 NSArray *dataToShare = @[url];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
            UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
            [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                              applicationActivities:nil];
            activityViewController.modalInPopover = YES;


            self.act = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
            [self.act presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.width/2) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            self.act.delegate = self;
```

I have added the :

> UIPopoverControllerDelegate

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

As soon that the

> UIPopoverController

is presented the view losses focus and doesn't register touches. Therefore, I can't handle touches outside the self.act rect space in order to force a dissmisal.

also...

```
NSArray *dataToShare = @[url];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
            UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
            [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                              applicationActivities:nil];
            activityViewController.modalInPopover = YES;

            UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [activityViewController popoverPresentationController];
            presentationController.sourceView = self.view; // if button or change to self.view.

            [self.parentViewController  presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and I tried to present the UIActivityViewController and UIPopoverController from the parent which didn't work aswell.

Please help, I lost half day on something this stupid which works on iOS 7.1 and not on iOS 8+ which is ridiculous and I still have no clue why.

I will try to add the cancel button which has also disappeared in iOS8+.

UPDATE 1:

Adding a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem didn't help...

```
UIButton *control = (UIButton *) sender;
                [control setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 300, 100, 100)];
                [control setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
                [barButtonItemView setCustomView:control];
                [self.popup presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItemView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

UPDATE 2 - 19.12.2014. (iOS 7.1. - 8.1.2):

The accepted answer works on iOS 8.1. I had some errors with iOS 7.1. so I modified it to work for iOS 7.1. I have stated on which devices the code works in the comments below the answer.

```
// publish - sharing
        NSArray *dataToShare = @[url];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
        UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                          applicationActivities:nil];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        NSLog(@" SHARING - 1 - ");
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }
    else
    {
        // Change Rect to position Popover
        NSLog(@" SHARING - 2 - ");
        self.popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];

        [self.popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3 / 5 ,
                                                      self.view.frame.size.width/2,
                                                      self.view.frame.size.width/10,
                                                      self.view.frame.size.width/10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just add this.

```
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
            [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                              applicationActivities:nil];
            activityViewController.modalInPopover = YES;

activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
```

Comment: I tested this code on iOS 8.1.2 (iPad) and it still doesn't work correctly. Clicking outside the share view does not dismiss it. Using only this code doesn't work at all :(

Comment: what is the trigger to share? (ex. pushing share button)  
I'll show a part of code which works at my programm.  
  
`- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender  
{  
    NSArray *items = @[something you want to share];  
  
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:applicationActivities];  
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;  
  
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];  
}`

Comment: The commented code you wrote is correct and works with iOS 8.1.2. Ty m8 :). I have edited your post, after the review I will accept the answer. The problem was in the "activityViewController.modalInPopover = YES;" line of code. Removing it solved the issue. I added some modifications so the code works for iOS 7.1.0 - iOS 8.1.2. The full modifications will be visible in the UPDATE code of the question. The code has been tested on (devices):iPod & iPad 2 (iOS 8.1.2) and all simulators (iOS 7.1. & 8.1).